# Hyperprior in PyMC3 hierarchical model

Tags: python, mcmc, pymc3

I'm trying to construct a hierarchical model from an academic paper in PyMC3, with many parameters. Here is the plate diagram for this model:

[image]

When I try to construct this model for PyMC3, I'm having trouble giving the hyperprior p (which is Beta-distributed and feeding a Bernoulli-distributed prior) a shape. What is the syntax for this? My incorrect model with inline comment illustrating my question is below:

```
with model:

    kappa = pm.Normal('kappa',mu=0.0,sd=5.0,shape=g)
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha',mu=10.0,sd=9.0,shape=j)
    gamma = pm.Normal('gamma',mu=0.0,sd=1.0,shape=(j,g))

    #conjugate prior for Bernoulli distribution
    p = pm.Beta('p',alpha=0.5,beta=0.5)
    #How can p have a shape argument and be passed below?
    beta = pm.Bernoulli('beta',p=p,shape=(j,g))

    #alpha_idx must have shape (j,egi) but be independent
    # of nlabels
    alpha_idx = np.vstack([ [x]*g for x in range(j)])

    #kappa_idx must have shape (j,g) but the value should be
    # independent of j
    kappa_idx = np.vstack([ [range(g)] * j])

    #The model itself
    mu = kappa[kappa_idx] + alpha[alpha_idx] + gamma*beta

    #sigma term. 
    eps = pm.Normal('eps',mu=1,tau=100) #Can't have mu=0 here

    obs = pm.Normal('obs',mu=mu,sd=eps,observed=df[data_channels])
```

Comment: @unutbu - It's unclear to me why `p` needs to have a shape. If you want to see the individual `p_jg`, can't you just extract that from the trace of `beta_jg`?

Comment: (I'm the OP, @unutbu just made an edit) It's not that I want to see the individual `p_jg`, it's that each `beta_jg` is independent of the others, so is it reasonable for them all to share a common success parameter prior?